# Is there a ready-made function for http_wait in telethon?

Tags: python, telethon

I need to use http_wait [link](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/service_messages#http-wait-long-poll) with telethon, are there already made functions in the library to use that specific method?

I need to receive messages as soon as they occur is large broadcast channels, now the updates come 5-20 seconds late

Answer (score 0):

Clients using the Telegram API, such as Telethon, connect to the Telegram servers directly via a TCP socket. While connected, Telegram decides when and where to deliver the updates. Telegram's API doesn't really offer a way to "poll" for these updates.

If Telegram is delivering them slowly, it's probably to reduce load, or because the channel is too large, or because the client is not being actively used. In essence, it's not something the library can "fix".